# jQuery append with html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a `Html.ActionLink` with jQuery like this

```
a.append("<li>@Html.ActionLink("e-TCGB","Inbox","Folder",new { Type = "1",DocumentTypeId = "3" },null)+"</li>");
```

and it is giving errors.

Being very inexperienced in javascript and jQuery I don't know if the error is because of wrong string parameter or because of doing something very wrong.

My guess is I'm making an escape character mistake but as I said, I don't know if what I'm doing is possible too.

Comment: Where is this snippet, in a javascript file?

Comment: yes it is in a seperate .js file

Comment: just use a normal hyperlink - why are you trying to use razor in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Razor is compiled at runtime - meaning its already done doing it's thing before your jQuery code is executed.

You can simply use a hyperlink though:

```
var li = $('<li>');
var link = $('<a href="/folder/inbox/?type=1?documenttypeid=3">e-TCGB</div>');
li.append(link);
a.append(li);
```

**UPDATE:**

Above, you can see two examples of generating elements using jQuery. The first is shorthand for generating a new `<li>` element:

```
$('<li>');
```

The second is generating a hyperlink tag. If you want to add attribute information you can do so in a number of different ways however I prefer to just write the tag out in long form when generating the element:

```
$('<a href="/folder/inbox/?type=1?documenttypeid=3">e-TCGB</div>');
```

Comment: This looks very neat but sadly didn't work as I planned it would. I'm probably putting it under wrong place in the jQuery.

Comment: @EgeBayrak - is any of this code being reached? Or is it an issue with the url?

Comment: Sorry, wrong alert. When I checked it with insector I can see the html is there but it's invisible. Css is probably making it invisible somehow.

Comment: I still need to give the link a name by the way. in <a href=...> Link Text </a> style. How can I do in accordance with the way you suggested?

Comment: @EgeBayrak I've updated my answer with the information you're looking for. It's just as trivial as *not doing* the shorthand for generating the hyperlink through jquery.

Answer (score 2):

@Html.ActionLink is a helper method in MVC designed to be used in the Razor views. It is executed on the server and processed as the Razor view is rendered to HTML.

jQuery is a JavaScript library that is used on the browser so execution here happens after the HTML has been received by the browser.

To recap, it is not possible to execute c# code (ActionLink) on the browser because it is a .net based server side method.

Comment: @EgeBayrak - No. These are all server side constructs / helper methods. jQuery is pure front end.